# Making sure a field is always null in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a parent class which is being extended by 3 different models. The parent class has a field called `foo` lets say, and this field needs to be always null for one of the sub-classes. How can I ensure this? Right now, I am using `null=True`, and `editable=False` constraints. However, these can be circumvented from the shell or an API if the field is exposed during object creation.

```
class ThirdSubclass(ParentClass):
    # Over-ridden field from abstract parent class
    foo = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
```

I am also using the PositiveSmallIntegerField since I want to allocate as little space as possible for this field. Anyway, how do I do this? Is over-riding the save method the only option? Ideally, I would love something within the field definition. Thanks!

Comment: I doubt that you can achieve this with the field definition - but overriding `model.save()` should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do this depends on how you expect your models to be used. Here are four possible approaches, in order of increasing robustness:

1. If all writes will come through default model forms:

   You can just set a default:

   ```
   class ThirdSubclass(ParentClass):
       foo = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None, editable=False)
   ```
2. If all writes will come through the use of model validation (that is, calling [`full_clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) before `save()`):

   You can use a validator:

   ```
   def validate_none(value):
       if value is not None:
           raise ValidationError("...")

   class ThirdSubclass(ParentClass):
       foo = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None, editable=False,
                                              validators=[validate_none])
   ```
3. If all writes will come through the model:

   You can override `save()`.

   ```
   class ThirdSubclass(ParentClass):
       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
           if self.foo is not None:
               raise ValueError("...")
           super().save(*args, **kwargs)
   ```
4. If writes can come from anywhere (for example, using [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) or raw SQL):

   You need a database-level constraint. Django has no model-level support for this, but you could create one by writing a custom migration and using `RunSQL` to create the constraint.

Of these I would consider 2 to be standard, and the most elegant if you don't need the protections of 3 and 4.

Comment: This is a good answer. I thought of another solution. Basically, check the field type for the `foo` field in the parent class `save()` method using `._meta.get_field('foo').get_internal_type()`, and if it is PositiveIntegerField, then manually set it to null again. This way, it will always be null as long as the field type is PositiveIntegerField. Would love to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: @TahmidKhanNafee: That seems functionally equivalent to overriding `ThirdSubclass.save()` but far less elegant. The whole point of using inheritance is to put specialized behavior on the subclass rather than switching on types.

Comment: Yes, but what if there was 12+ subclasses that needed `foo` to always be null? Wouldn't over-riding so many classes be an issue?

Comment: @TahmidKhanNafee: If that were the case then you would create a new intermediate class to implement that behavior and have the 12+ descend from that. Class-based inheritance is not a panacea for all code reuse issues, but if you're going to use Django's model inheritance you should stick with the paradigm.