# How to enforce database constraints between two foreign keys on a join table?

Tags: django, database, django-models, orm, model

I am trying to enforce a constraint between two foreign keys on a join table, and I don't know whether I can do it using the database, or whether I should do it through my app, or my ORM.

Here are my tables:

```
Dataset

Tag
 - Dataset: FK
 - name: string (eg: "park", "church", etc)

Place
 - Dataset: FK
 - latitude
 - longitude

PlaceTag (my join table)
 - Tag: FK
 - Place: FK
 - note: string (eg: "this place is my favorite park")
```

I want to enforce the constraint that each PlaceTag has a Tag and a Place that belong to the same Dataset. Should I do this using the database, or my app? Or should I re-structure my models to enforce this constraint more easily?

FWIW, this is an open-source project, and my PR for creating these tables is up here: https://github.com/mapseed/api/pull/161/files The project is using Django, if that helps.

Comment: Briefly, the best approach depends on how you anticipate using the tables. For example, if all writes will come from code that calls `full_clean()` (e.g. forms), putting your check in `PlaceTag.clean()` makes the most sense. Here's a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914154/making-sure-a-field-is-always-null-in-django/52920468#52920468). Note that Django is adding [declarative syntax for check contraints](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.CheckConstraint) in Django 2.2.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thank you for this answer. It's helpful to know that it's not reasonable to do this in the database, and I can "enforce" this using Django's models. But I am looking forward to using Django 2.2's CheckConstraint - perhaps that will give me the database solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of "enforcing" (note the quotation marks) this in Django would be to override the `PlaceTag`'s `save()` method. In there you can raise an exception whenever `self.place.dataset != self.tag.dataset`. Yet you should note that there are situations in which Django will not call the custom `save()` method of a model:

1. When calling the `update()` method on a queryset. This method is meant for bulk updates and hence, for performance reasons, proceeds with the update directly at a database level [(reference)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once).
2. Inside (data) migrations custom `save()` methods are not available.

In these two situations the approach I propose will not be useful to enforce the constraint (hence the quotation marks at the beginning). This is of course not the same and not as strong as enforcing this at a database level. Anyway I don't think there is a portable way (i.e. available in any or most SQL database engines) of enforcing such a condition since checking it will require a join on other tables, yet I may be wrong on this one.

Comment: This answer, along with Kevin's answer above, helped me add the validation that I needed. I overrode my model's `.save` method to have it call `.full_clean`, which I overrode as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean